# Unknown column 'PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `status_id`, `status_type_id`, `status_code`, `sequence_id`, `description` FROM (`maya_status`) WHERE `status_id` = PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT LIMIT 0
>
> Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website-development/www.xxx.com/widgets/controls/models/entity_model.php
>
> Line Number: 18

Heres My Query To Model

```
$this->data['result'] = $this->entity_model->get('maya_status','status_id,status_type_id,status_code,sequence_id,description', 'status_id = '.$this->uri->segment(4),NULL,NULL,true);
```

And Here's My Model

```
function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){
    
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
    $this->db->where($where);
    }
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result($array) : $query->row() ;
    return $result;
}
```

and if i change AND--> `$this->db->where($where);` to `$this->db->where('status_id','PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT');` i've got an error Message: Trying to get property of non-object..

Comment: So the obvious is: does table maya_status have a column called PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT.  Of did you mean to have a variable of type string that is evaluated?

Comment: Is `PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT` a constant? If so, remove the quotes around it.

Comment: you might want to catch first the uri segment you are passing if it is real or a phony,

Comment: PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT is not constant, i get value from the url *valueId= PHOTO_ACTIVE_NOT 

--- Okay, my question was fix, with the below answer ;) thanks, i've got some problem, for appears result in view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your where call, e.g.

'status_id = "' . $this->uri->segment(4) . '"'

To make it:

```
$this->data['result'] = $this->entity_model->get('maya_status','status_id,status_type_id,status_code,sequence_id,description', 'status_id = "' . $this->uri->segment(4) . '"',NULL,NULL,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks, this what i need, but ive got some problem output in view, like this..

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

==== this is in my view ===

/////-->> echo $result->status_id ?>"  />

==== this is in my view ===

what do i'm wrong of getting value in array..?

***Thank you for your time :) !